# Structure in script I believe that I'm getting wrong. Have patience, I'm trying to structure my coding to where I have a better understanding

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a project that of Simon Says in javascript that I've been taking my time with so that I can build a better understanding in the logic that when I write code I'll be able to surely explain and understand.

Here's the code output in web console on Chrome:
[image: screen shot of web console]

In the console log I have in output of 5, yet, when you look closely to the right where the code 5 outputs "index.html 61:3" there the number 95 in an oval shape before the index.html.

This starts from 5 and continues to add 5 which now reach 95.

My coding I have been practicing to perfect any input will be helpful. 
Here's my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, XML, XHTML, JavaScript">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2 id="clickNumber">0</h2>
      <button id="red1" class="colors" onclick="red()"></button>
      <button id="blue1" class="colors" onclick="blue()"></button>
      <button  id="green1" class="colors" onclick="green()"></button>
      <button id="yellow1" class="colors" onclick="yellow()"></button>
    <script>
    //
    simonArr=[];
      simonArr[0] = red;
      simonArr[1] = blue;
      simonArr[2] = green;
      simonArr[3] = yellow;
      simonAr = [
       document.getElementById('red1'), document.getElementById('blue1'),                            
       document.getElementById('green1'), document.getElementById('yellow1')
      ];


    function red(){
     document.getElementById('red1').style.opacity = ".25";
       setInterval( function(){
           document.getElementById('red1').style.opacity = "1";
          }, 3000);
    }

    function blue(){
    document.getElementById('blue1').style.opacity = ".25";
    setInterval( function(){
           document.getElementById('blue1').style.opacity = "1";
          }, 3000);
    }
    function green(){
    document.getElementById('green1').style.opacity = ".25";
    setInterval( function(){
           document.getElementById('green1').style.opacity = "1";
          }, 3000);
    }
    function yellow(){
    document.getElementById('yellow1').style.opacity = ".25";
    setInterval( function(){
           document.getElementById('yellow1').style.opacity = "1";
          }, 3000);

    }


    var mySimon = setInterval(simonMix, 2000);
    var simonX = simonAr.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*simonAr.length)+1);

    function simonMix(){
    for(var i=0;i<simonAr.length;i++){
       if(simonX[i].style.opacity = ".25"===-1){
    simonX[i].style.opacity ="1";   
  };
      console.log(simonX)

      }
    }



    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: ok..the output of the program is suppose to do a random sequence of color fades yet it's not producing the random sequence or fading.

Comment: The question is not clear. Please read this [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Highlight what is the desired behavior and what is the problem exactly.  Also it would be helpful if you limit your code to a simple example demonstrating the issue. Hint: click `<>` to create a runnable example. But anyway this part looks really suspicios `simonX[i].style.opacity = ".25"===-1` what are you trying to do with this line of code?

Comment: the if condition to test the value for true and false. if true or false this occurs. yet, I have wrote the if statement with true and false condition and without true or false condition.